# I'm having a difficult time finding out how to create style resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I've tried to create *Style* resources for the WPF application I'm developing based on a style guide presented to me from a UI/UX design house. After setting window and control background color to the desired shade of blue, I'm seeing the following:

1. *ListView* headers have a white background
2. For a *TabControl*, the selected *TabItem* header background is white while I need to set it to a different shade of blue
3. The border for a *PopUp* for a button context menu is thick and an arbitrary gray color
4. I successfully created a default Button Style resource, which excludes the "x:Key" attribute and then created a different Button Style for "Primary" buttons. However, the Primary Button Style doesn't fully work, as the text background color is wrong and the text is in the upper lefthand corner of the button.
5. For *ToolBar* controls, the overflow button is white rather than the blue color I set for the *ToolBar* Background

I've performed exhaustive searches to find examples of *Style* resources to fix these issues, none of them fixed these issues. The only things I've found were what I'll call inline styles for declared controls in a *Window*. I tried copying the *ControlTemplates* from these examples to use in my global resource *Style*, to no avail.

What I'm figuring out is that most WPF *Controls* have multiple "parts" that need to have their *ContentPresenter* set. I've found nothing from Microsoft or anywhere else that explains that for each type of WPF *Control*.

I've attached a couple of images that show the issues I'm having.
[image: The Wrong Text Background in ListBox]

[image: Wrong ListView Header and Selected Tab Item Header Background, ToolBar OverFlow button background Wrong]

[image: Primary Button Style Text Position and Background Wrong]

## Here is the xaml for my *Control* *ResourceDictionary*:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!--The Primary Button Variant-->
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PrimaryButton">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource teal-1Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource button-priimary-borderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="0"/>


                    <ContentPresenter
                     x:Name="cp"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource bluegreenBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource bluegreenBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource petrolBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource metallic-blueBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--The Standard Button Variant-->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource teal-3Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource button-standard-borderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="0"/>

                    <ContentPresenter
                     x:Name="cp"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource dark-tealBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource button-standard-borderBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource deep-tealBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource steel-greyBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource teal-3Brush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource dark-grey-blueBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource teal-3Brush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--The Image Radius Button-->
<Style x:Key="ImageRadiusButton"
    TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="5"/>
                    

                    <ContentPresenter
                     x:Name="cp"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--The Image Button-->
<Style x:Key="ImageButton"
    TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                    <ContentPresenter
                     x:Name="cp"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--The Combo Box-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border
          x:Name="Border" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          CornerRadius="0"
          Background="{StaticResource blue-2Brush}" 
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource button-standard-borderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="1" />
        <Border 
          Grid.Column="0"
          CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" 
          Background="{StaticResource blue-2Brush}" 
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="1" />
        <Path 
          x:Name="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"     
          Fill="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="DarkGray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Height="25" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="8,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                        Style="{x:Null}" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                        Focusable="True" 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Visibility="Hidden"
                        Foreground="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid 
                            Name="DropDown"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource blue-2Brush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource button-standard-borderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource navyBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource dark-grey-blueBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource dark-tealBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource button-standard-borderBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource teal-3Brush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--The ToolBar-->
<Style TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
</Style>

<!--The TextBlock-->
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"/>
</Style>

<!--The TextBox-->
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"/>
</Style>

<!--The CheckBox-->
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteBrush}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TabControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource blackBrush}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TabPanel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource blackBrush}"/>
</Style>

<BorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="BorderGapMaskConverter"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource blackBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <Border Name="Header" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}" ConverterParameter="7">
                                <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## Here is the Color *ResourceDictionary*:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Color x:Key="black">#FF000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="blue-1">#FF002F50</Color>
<Color x:Key="blue-2">#FF001E33</Color>
<Color x:Key="blue-3">#FF00121D</Color>
<Color x:Key="bluegreen">#FF007080</Color>
<Color x:Key="button-priimary-border">#FFA3B6C3</Color>
<Color x:Key="button-standard-border">#FF61686C</Color>
<Color x:Key="dark-grey-blue">#FF314C5E</Color>
<Color x:Key="dark-teal">#FF003B51</Color>
<Color x:Key="deep-teal">#FF004B61</Color>
<Color x:Key="green">#FF6DD400</Color>
<Color x:Key="light-blue">#FF90AFC4</Color>
<Color x:Key="marine-blue">#FF002F50</Color>
<Color x:Key="metallic-blue">#FF527389</Color>
<Color x:Key="navy">#FF002741</Color>
<Color x:Key="petrol">#FF005D77</Color>
<Color x:Key="pinkish-grey-78">#C8BFBFBF</Color>
<Color x:Key="red-1">#FFFF001B</Color>
<Color x:Key="red-2">#FFFF5466</Color>
<Color x:Key="steel-grey">#FF80868A</Color>
<Color x:Key="teal-1">#FF008B9F</Color>
<Color x:Key="teal-2">#FF006F7F</Color>
<Color x:Key="teal-3">#FF001E33</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource blue-1}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="blackBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource black}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-1Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource blue-1}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-2Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource blue-2}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-3Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource blue-3}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="bluegreenBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource bluegreen}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="button-priimary-borderBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="button-standard-borderBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="dark-grey-blueBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource dark-grey-blue}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="dark-tealBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource dark-teal}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="deep-tealBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource deep-teal}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="greenBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource green}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="light-blueBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource light-blue}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="marine-blueBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource marine-blue}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="metallic-blueBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource metallic-blue}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="navyBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource navy}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="petrolBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource petrol}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="pinkish-grey-78Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource pinkish-grey-78}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="red-1Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource red-1}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="red-2Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource red-2}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="steel-greyBrush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource steel-grey}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-1Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource teal-1}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-2Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource teal-2}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-3Brush" 
                 Color="{StaticResource teal-3}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="whiteBrush" Color="White"/>
```

Comment: Basic restyling can be straightforward enough, but once you get into the realms of needing to restyle the different control states (clicked, hover, disabled, etc) then the only solution as you've found is to completely "re-template" it. If it helps, you can find the default MS templates here, for you to copy and adapt as needed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewStephens! I've now started doing just that, but I'm having 2 issues related to a common button style. 

1. Everything works fine for all states but setting the disabled foreground state.
2. There is a single button in the entire app that isn't applying any of the style - this one weirds me out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I took @AndrewStevens advice and re-templated all of the global controls successfully, **EXCEPT** that I'm having 2 issues with my **Button** style:

1. The weirdest thing is that a single button out of dozens in my app so far doesn't have any of the templating applied.
2. I've been unable to set the text color for the button when **IsEnabled**="*False*".

I've done my usual plethora of Google searches to no avail for either of these issues.

If anybody has any clue on either of these, I'd appreciate the help.

## Here is the Button style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonRestTextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonRestBackGroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonRestBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="0">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonHoverBorderBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonPressedBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonPressedBorderBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonFocusBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonDisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource StandardButtonDisabledBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## And, here is the Colors ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="black">#FF000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="blue-1">#FF002F50</Color>
    <Color x:Key="blue-2">#FF001E33</Color>
    <Color x:Key="blue-3">#FF00121D</Color>
    <Color x:Key="bluegreen">#FF007080</Color>
    <Color x:Key="button-priimary-border">#FFA3B6C3</Color>
    <Color x:Key="button-standard-border">#FF61686C</Color>
    <Color x:Key="dark-grey-blue">#FF314C5E</Color>
    <Color x:Key="dark-teal">#FF003B51</Color>
    <Color x:Key="deep-teal">#FF004B61</Color>
    <Color x:Key="green">#FF6DD400</Color>
    <Color x:Key="light-blue">#FF90AFC4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="marine-blue">#FF002F50</Color>
    <Color x:Key="metallic-blue">#FF527389</Color>
    <Color x:Key="navy">#FF002741</Color>
    <Color x:Key="petrol">#FF005D77</Color>
    <Color x:Key="pinkish-grey-78">#C8BFBFBF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="red-1">#FFFF001B</Color>
    <Color x:Key="red-2">#FFFF5466</Color>
    <Color x:Key="steel-grey">#FF80868A</Color>
    <Color x:Key="teal-1">#FF008B9F</Color>
    <Color x:Key="teal-2">#FF006F7F</Color>
    <Color x:Key="teal-3">#FF001E33</Color>
    <Color x:Key="defaultTextColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="disabledTextColor">#A19F9D</Color>
    <Color x:Key="windowSectionBorderColor">#001E33</Color>
    <Color x:Key="transparentColor">Transparent</Color>
    <Color x:Key="disabledBackgroundColor">#FF001E33</Color>
    <Color x:Key="windowBackgroundColor">#FF002F50</Color>
    <Color x:Key="defaultFocusBorder">White</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource blue-1}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TransparentBrush" Color="{StaticResource transparentColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WhiteBrush" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="disabledBorderBrush" Color="#A19F9D"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultHeaderGroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="defaultTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="disabledTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource disabledTextColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="windowSectionBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource windowSectionBorderColor}"/>

    <!--The Primary Button Brushes-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonRestBackGroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-1}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonRestBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonRestTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonFocusBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-1}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonFocusBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonFocusTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonPressedBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonPressedBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource bluegreen}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonPressedTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonHoverBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonHoverBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource bluegreen}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonHoverTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonDisabledBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonDisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource petrol}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryButtonDisabledTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource disabledTextColor}"/>

    <!--The Standard Button Brushes-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonRestBackGroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonRestBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonRestTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonFocusBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonFocusBorderBrush" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonFocusTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonPressedBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource steel-grey}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonPressedBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-2}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonPressedTextBrush" Color="White"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonHoverBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonHoverBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource dark-teal}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonHoverTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonDisabledBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource dark-grey-blue}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonDisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StandardButtonDisabledTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource disabledTextColor}"/>

    <!--The ComboBox Colors-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxRestBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource blue-2}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxRestBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxRestTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource teal-3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusBorderBrush" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHoverBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource dark-teal}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHoverBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxHoverTextrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource deep-teal}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource steel-grey}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource defaultTextColor}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDiabledBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource navy}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDiabledBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource dark-grey-blue}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDisabledTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource disabledTextColor}"/>

    <!--The root brushes-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="blackBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource black}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-1Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource blue-1}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-2Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource blue-2}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="blue-3Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource blue-3}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="bluegreenBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource bluegreen}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="button-priimary-borderBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource button-priimary-border}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="button-standard-borderBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource button-standard-border}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="dark-grey-blueBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource dark-grey-blue}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="dark-tealBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource dark-teal}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="deep-tealBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource deep-teal}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="greenBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource green}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="light-blueBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource light-blue}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="marine-blueBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource marine-blue}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="metallic-blueBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource metallic-blue}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="navyBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource navy}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="petrolBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource petrol}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="pinkish-grey-78Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource pinkish-grey-78}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="red-1Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource red-1}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="red-2Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource red-2}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="steel-greyBrush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource steel-grey}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-1Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource teal-1}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-2Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource teal-2}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="teal-3Brush" 
                     Color="{StaticResource teal-3}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Re the disabled text colour, I don't see anything in your style to do this. Have you tried adding the line `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value=...` inside your existing trigger (`<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">`)?
Regarding the one button that isn't being styled, can you post the xaml of that button along with the xaml of a button that *does* appear as expected, so we can compare the two?

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewStephens. I have tried adding the foreground color setter, but it doesn't help. Regarding the one button...(sheepish grin), I found that the code (I'm developing a new product in WPF using behind code from the current WinForms version), was setting the background color for a special purpose. I've fixed that.

Comment: Strange one about the foreground. Have you tried the VS live visual tree feature? Highlight a button and look at its Foreground property in the tree - this will tell you where it's getting the colour value from.

Comment: @AndrewStephens, I just used that and it tells me it is coming from my button style ContentPresenter, so I have no idea.